# Having issues passing a delegate from NSWindowController subclass to my ViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa, delegates, protocols, nswindowcontroller

I'm having issues with passing a custom protocol (MainWindowControllerProtocol) to the EditorViewController from the MainWindowController, which is subclass of NSWindowController. Please help.

**EditorViewController.swift**

```
extension EditorViewController: MainWindowControllerProtocol {
    func didOpenFile() {
        print("TODO: Open File") // never called, but it should be
    }
}

class EditorViewController: NSViewController {
    // - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var treeOutlineView: NSOutlineView!
    @IBOutlet var codeTextView: NSTextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var counterTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageTextField: NSTextField!

    //public var editor = Editor()
    //var rootNode: Node?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        //rootNode = Path(Path.userDownloads).node

        // Issue is here
        if let windowController = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.windowController as? MainWindowController {
            windowController.delegate = self
        }
        else {
            print("Doesnt work") // prints this
        }

        //treeOutlineView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**MainWindowController**

```
public protocol MainWindowControllerProtocol {
    func didOpenFile()
}

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    var delegate: MainWindowControllerProtocol?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }
    @IBAction func openFile(_ sender: Any) {
        print("In here") // this is called?
        delegate?.didOpenFile() // but this never is apparently
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you present `MainWindowController`?

Comment: `MainWindowController` doesn’t seem to be instantiated inside `EditorViewController`. When you do instantiate it, you can set its delegate to `self’`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622660/10785142) should help.

> This method might return nil if the application’s nib file hasn’t
>   finished loading, if the receiver is not active, or if the application
>   is hidden.

Have you checked if `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow` is nil or just `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.windowController` cannot be casted to your controller class ?